# Tortoise SVN error "Symbolic links are not supported on this platform"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, symlink

When I try to update a sub folder of my project, tortoise SVN gives me the error

```
Working copy "c:\project\extensions" locked.
"c:\project\extensions" is already locked
```

I've tried to cleanup from the `\extensions` level and also the `c:\project` level, both of which give me-

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
c:\projects
Symbolic links are not supported on this platform
```

What is going on?

Comment: Do people working on UNIX/Linux or Mac OS also work on your project?

Comment: Yes they do ... Linux and Mac. Could there be some issues there?

Comment: Can you please help me out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980708/svn-symbolic-links-are-not-supported-on-this-platform-windows-8-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Subversion can version symbolic links, Subversion on Windows does not support them (true symlink support didn't come to NTFS until Windows 7 was released). One of the other users of your repository has apparently created, added & committed one or more symlinks.

In place of the symlink, IIRC Subversion will give you a text file with a note inside telling you where that symlink points to.

You will need to ask the other users to remove the symlinks, possibly replacing them with file-level externals to simulate the behavior. It's not ideal, but it's all you can really do for now if you'll have Windows clients using the repository

Comment: Thanks - this answer is absolutely correct. It's annoying that things like this can happen!

Comment: Can you please help me out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980708/svn-symbolic-links-are-not-supported-on-this-platform-windows-8-1

Comment: Junction support (symlinks for directories) existed since NTFS 3, which appeard in Windows 2000, 15 years ago. Symlinks for files, appeard in NTFS 5 in Windows Vista, 9 years ago. I just think svn or/and tortoise developpers are simply bone idle. They lost motivation since git killed them maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like now this issue is caused by OneDrive syncing a file in question which appears as a symlink to TortoiseSVN. 
I resolved it by copying the file to a non-One Drive backed location, updating SVN from there, and all worked.

Answer (score -1):

Symbolic links are supported as of TortoiseSVN 1.8. It appears that this error message is a left over from days when they were not supported. Should be reported to the devs to adjust it.

Comment: I've been trying to find any info on windows symlink support in SVN 1.8, but I have come up empty so far, do you have any links with details?

Comment: I have tortoise 1.8.2 with svn 1.8.3 on windows 7, and I tell you, it is still not supported. still whining.