# svn: Symbolic links are not supported on this platform - Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, windows, svn, windows-8, symlink

I have a folder with few images as `Symbolic links` now when i try to check in the folder it gives me the below error:

```
Trying to use an unsupported feature
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Symbolic links are not supported on this platform
```

I am using `SVN - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x` and i am on Windows 8.1 OS.

I have looked into many posts related to the above query but i havent found any soultion or fix to this, as i have to check in the symlinks.

And also can i check in the same by switching from windows to linux ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I add a symbolic link to subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056092/what-happens-if-i-add-a-symbolic-link-to-subversion)

Answer (score 4):

Subversion does not support symlinks on Windows. If you created symlinks on your filesystem in Windows (they are supported by the OS/NTFS), Subversion can't handle them. Since you're probably going to be using this project on both Windows and Linux (since you're committing from Windows, and asking about Linux), you won't be able to use symlinks. If you want to eliminate duplicated files in the repository, use file externals in place of symlinks.

Comment: I have projects with symlinks which i am going to use only with Windows machine, like project1(with symlinks) i am going to check in into my repo, and then i am going to checkout the same project on another windows machine.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that Subversion doesn't support those symlinks on Windows and you'll need to stop using them. If you were exclusively using Linux you could use them.

Comment: i have this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056092/what-happens-if-i-add-a-symbolic-link-to-subversion#  answer from David W, but how can i run that scripts and use that, can you please help me out ?

Comment: If you're referring to "If you want symbolic links, create them during the build/deploy part of your process as part of your build/deploy scripts, and not as a repository artifact." then no, I cannot help you with rewriting the entirety of your build scripts for this purpose. Are you sure you fully understand the answer that David wrote there?